# create hard custom button

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I can not figure out how to construct this button. I need help in the creation of this, note that the strip is not painted when the button is active. What elements should I use?

on link you can look this button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mmJ0.png

```
    UIButton *clone = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [clone setTitle:strDate forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clone setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    clone.frame = CGRectMake(19, post_offer_top*(i-1)+22, 281, 75);
    clone.tag = my_id;
   // [clone setTitle:[[buttons objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    clone.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    clone.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 31, 0, 0);
    [clone setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clone setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clone.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PF DinDisplay Pro" size:10]];
    [clone.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize buttons like this [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]

Comment: all icons and text - its background static? or i should use 2 subviews?